# Why `import Scalaz._` is shadowing `import scalaz.std.scalaFuture._`

Tags: scala, scalaz

Why

`import Scalaz._`

is shadowing

`import scalaz.std.scalaFuture._` ?

When I remove `import Scalaz._`, it works, but I would understand what happens.

Comment: There is a general problem in Scala that implicits, either of the same type or of the same name, can shadow each other.

Comment: If you use `import Scalaz._`, you shouldn't use the `scalaz.std.x` and `scalaz.syntax.y` imports for exactly this reason.